# Oracle 10g | Relation between Stored Procedure and Jobs

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jobs

I have a problem.
I have 5 stored procedure name and I would like to know which jobs are using each of this stored procedure.

I have queried the all_source in the stored procedure name but ther was not the solution.
Anybody got an idea?

Thanks.

Comment: you mean dbms_scheduler jobs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select job, what from user_jobs;

select job_name, job_action from USER_SCHEDULER_JOBS;
```

Comment: And if you have DBA access, better look in all jobs.

Comment: SQL> select * from dba_jobs;

no rows selected

SQL>  select * from all_jobs;

no rows selected

SQL>  select * from user_jobs;

no rows selected

SQL>

Comment: @user2474698 dba_scheduler_jobs ?

Comment: the result of select job, what from user_jobs; and dba_jobs and all_jobs

Comment: how will this query solve the issue? How will you get stored procedure name ?

Comment: @loki what column is the action that the job execute, if there are jobs that execute the SPs, than the name of the SP could be seen in what column.

Comment: in dba_jobs is empty but in dba_scheduler_jobs is a lot of job...
I dont understand why is it.

Comment: I have found the solution. It's little bit circumstantial but it works.
1.From DBA_SCHEDULER_JOBS query the jobs.
2. Get one of the jobs metadata with dbms_metadata.get_ddl
3. examine the metadate.

I have found there the wanted stored procedure.
I have lucky becas I just had 45 jobs.